# calculate percentages at the different grouping levels without creating separate percentage formulas for each group level

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

In Crystal Report,I am looking for a way to calculate percentages at the different grouping levels without creating separate percentage formulas for each group level.
can someone please tell me is there a way to do that or I have to create separate percentage formulas for each group level?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the saperately for all grouping levels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. how about if I come up with a formula like this, (let's say I have three grouping in my report) if grouping=group 1, then (group1 numerator/group1 denominator)*100. if grouping=group2, then (group2 numerator/group2 denominator)*100. if grouping=group3, then (group3 numerator/group3 denominator)*100. Does anyone have any idea on how to create a formula like that?? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the formula but here also you are creating 3 calculations the only difference is you are clubbing into one formula instead create 3 forumlas then debugging will be easy task if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to reduce the numbers of formula in the report. Otherwise, I will have about 20 to 25 formulas in my report. Any idea on how to create (coding) such formula??Thanks.